# Comparing objects inside an Array for Sorting

Tags: java

I have been trying to compare objects in an Array by one if its properties so that I can sort the objects in the Array into a descending order. Here is the sample code: The array is `Candidate[][]`

```
    System.out.println("How many positions for this election? > ");
    numberOfPositions = sc.nextInt();
    Candidate Candidate[][] = new Candidate[numberOfPositions][];
    PoliticalParty Parties[][] = new PoliticalParty[numberOfPositions][];
    for(int i=0;i<numberOfPositions;i++){
        String name;
        String politicalParty;
        System.out.println("Enter position name > ");
        position = sc.next();
        System.out.println("How many seats? > ");
        numberOfSeats = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("How many candidates? > ");
        numberOfCandidates = sc.nextInt();
        Candidate[i] = new Candidate[numberOfCandidates+1];
        Candidate[i].sort(votes); //<--------------------------This is what im trying//
```

Wherein (votes) is an int derived from a text file using this code:

```
System.out.println("Enter file name > ");
    filename = sc.next();
    try {
        filescan = new Scanner(new File(filename));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        //Logger.getLogger(Election.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    String L = System.lineSeparator();
    filescan.useDelimiter(L);
    while (filescan.hasNext()) {
        numberOfVoters++;
        line = filescan.next();
        for(int x=0,j=0;j<line.length();j++){
            switch(line.charAt(j)){
                case ',':
                    x++;
                    break;
                case ' ':
                    break;
                default:
                    int y = line.charAt(j)-48;
                    //Integer.parseInt(line.charAt(j).toString());
                    Candidate[x][y].addVote();
                    break;
            }
        }
```

Wherein (vote) is encapsulated in another Class:

```
public class Candidate{
int votes = 0;
String politicalParty;

public Candidate(String name, String politicalParty) {
    super(name);
    this.politicalParty = politicalParty;
}

public void addVote() {
    this.votes++;
    //return votes;
}

public int getVotes() {
    return votes;
}

@Override
public String getName() {
    return getName();
}

public void displayFields(){
    System.out.println(this.getName() + " (" + getPoliticalParty() + ") - " + votes);
}

public String getPoliticalParty() {
    return politicalParty;
}

public void setPoliticalParty(String politicalParty) {
    this.politicalParty = politicalParty;
}
}
```

Comment: Take a look to Comparable interface http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arrays have a premade sort method. The [Javadoc for Arrays.sort(Object[] a)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D%29) mentions a "natural ordering". The Comparable interface exists to provide the natural order.

**Step 1**

Apply the interface to your class.

- `public class Candidate implements Comparable<Candidate> {`

**Step 2**

Implement the `compareTo(Candidate c) {}` method in your class.

Read the [Javadoc for](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) `compareTo()` contract. In general, it must return a positive, zero, or negative number if `this.property` is greater than, equal to, or less than `c.property`, respectively. `property` is the field upon which you are comparing.

- Tip: If `property` is a String, you can simply reuse String's `compareTo()`

  - `return this.property.compareto(c.property);`
- Tip: If `property` is an integer (like votes), you can cleverly create a positive, zero, or negative number by taking the difference.

  - `return this.votes - c.votes;`

**Step 3**

Sort your array.

Now that your object is comparable, call `Collections.sort(list)` if you have a Collection or `Arrays.sort(list)` you have an Array of objects.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use an ArrayList to store the elements to be sorted and then you'll have 2 options: make your items Comparable (interface) or create a Comparator (interface):

```
public class Candidate implements Comparable<Candidate> {
    ...

public int compareTo(Candidate c) {
    ... //compare here the attributes of this and c
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Quick question, short answer: [`java.util.Arrays.sort()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort%28T%5b%5d,%20java.util.Comparator%29)

Comment: You missed the `Comparator` or impleementing `Comparable`.

Comment: Thought the OP would figure that one out for himself pretty quickly :)

Answer (score 0):

1. Why your variable starts from capital letter? It should be like all variables from small.
2. You should use collections for storing custom data types, then you can easy sort it using `Collections.sort(List<T> list, Comparator<? super T> c)` and define your own `Comparator` whatever you want.